# Comment accorder "se disputer": "les chiens se sont disputé(s) un os", "elles se sont disputé(es)", "elle s'est disputé(e) avec lui"?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, accord, participe-passé, verbes-pronominaux

Si je ne me trompe pas, le verbe "disputer" a plusieurs constructions possibles:

1. ***Se disputer avec qqn.***
2. ***Disputer qqn.***
3. **Disputer qqchose à qqn** (ou juste ***disputer qqchose***.)

-->Quelqu'un peut me le confirmer?

Donc, je voudrais savoir comment faire avec ces accords:

- "les chiens se sont disputé(s) un os" -->Je pense que c'est ***disputé*** sans accord car [les chiens ont disputé un os **à eux-même**] donc "se" est COI?
- "elles se sont disputé(es)"-->Je pense que c'est ***disputées*** accord avec "se" car [elles ont disputé **elles même**] donc "se" est COD?
- "elle s'est disputé(e) avec lui"-->Je pense que c'est ***disputée*** accorde avec "se" car "se" n'a pas ne fonction logique?
  -->Mais je reste incertain car est-ce vraiment un "se" non fonctionnel ou la construction est-elle [elle a disputé **elle même** avec lui] et donc "se" est COD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Les trois sens listés sont attestés ; le second est un verbe très familier, à ne pas utiliser dans du texte assez formel. (**Note**  pour se renseigner en beaucoup de détail  sur du vocabulaire, utiliser le TLFi (aussi appelé « site du cnrtl » : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/)

2/ Exact ;

3/ Exact ; l'usage est respecté dans ce cas :  [elles se sont disputé qqc](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elles%20se%20sont%20disput%C3%A9%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr),
[elles se sont disputées](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elles%20se%20sont%20disput%C3%A9es%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr). Cependant, la raison n'est pas la règle du COD. Le verbe est un verbe pronominal idiomatique et de ce fait il s'accorde toujours.

> Si le verbe est essentiellement pronominal (il n’existe qu’à la forme avec pronom réfléchi), ou si c’est un verbe pronominal idiomatique (qui existe aussi à la forme non pronominale, mais avec un autre sens), le participe passé s’accorde toujours.
>
> http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/accpp.html#497

L'idée « elles ont disputé elles-mêmes » n'est pas correcte ; « se » n'a pratiquement pas de sens dans cette construction.

4/ Exact ; Le contenu sémantique de « se » est impossible à interpréter (ou, en d'autres termes, « se » n'a pas de fonction logique). La règle est scupuleusement observée dans ce cas : « [elles s'est disputée](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elle%20s%27est%20disput%C3%A9e%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) ».

[image]

Comment: Bonjour LPH, Je vous remercie. L'explication est très claire. Bonne journée.